# Getting MongoDB + Spring MVC to speak UTF8

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, utf-8

I have an application that is based on mongodb + spring and a RESTful interface (via Spring MVC).

When we send a request to the server to make an update (e.g. a user field), and the field has non-ascii character (e.g. Cyrillic / Russian) it is saved to mongo but when we read it back through the interface we get garbled chars.

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: MongoDB supports [UTF-8] (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Internationalized+Strings) - can you return the data correctly when using the mongo shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found out that the issue was with how JSoup treats non-ascii chars. Now it works.